# Debian bootup just stops on Thinkpad T14

Tags: debian, boot

I've got a new Thinkpad T14 (AMD), and I'm trying to install Debian 11 on. Everything installed correctly, but when it boots up, it just sits on this screen. It's not always exactly the same position, but it just doesn't move.

That said, I can use Ctrl+Alt+F1 and switch to a login prompt, and even run `startx` to get into KDE.

I've run `dmesg` under root, and I can't see anything that looks particularly out of place.

Any suggestions what I can even look at? Thanks

[image: Screen]

Comment: Once you are logged in, you can use `journalctl -xe` to see what's actually causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I've done this, but I don't see anything obvious in there either, to be fair, I'm not 100% sure what to look for.
There's some orange lines referring to audio and network, but that's about it

Comment: So I found out the problem... sddm was not launching. I've installed lightdm and everything is fine.
Bit odd, but I'll take it